# Looping event listener through radio buttons. Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, loops, slider, addeventlistener

Yesterday I was trying to make a slider on radio buttons with JavaScript and after few hours finished with code cited below. I'm quite new to JavaScript but know that repeating actions should be placed in a loop. So is there any chance to do that?

```
var slide = document.getElementsByClassName('slide');

var radio = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-form [type="radio"]');


var x = function () {
    for( var i = 0; i < slide.length; i += 1) {
        if(radio[i].checked === true) {
            slide[i].style.display = "flex";
        } 
    }
}

x();

radio[0].addEventListener('change', function () {
    slide[0].style.display = "flex";
    slide[1].style.display = "none";
    slide[2].style.display = "none";
});

radio[1].addEventListener('change', function () {
    slide[0].style.display = "none";
    slide[1].style.display = "flex";
    slide[2].style.display = "none";
});

radio[2].addEventListener('change', function () {
    slide[0].style.display = "none";
    slide[1].style.display = "none";
    slide[2].style.display = "flex";
});
```

And the second question is, can I somehow bind my radio[number] with slide[same number], so I could just change classes like in this example:

```
$("input[type=radio]:not(:checked)").addClass("hiddenRadio");
```

Again, I'm interested in minimizing my code (because there could be ten or more buttons), so is there any way to apply changing of the class in 1-2 lines of code or in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below solution. I think this will solve your problem.

```js
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-form [type="radio"]');

function hideAllSlide() {
  slides.forEach(function(slide) {
    slide.style.display = 'none';
  });
}

radios.forEach(function(radio, index) {
  if(radio.checked){
    slides[index].style.display = 'flex';
  }
  
  radio.addEventListener('change', function() {
      hideAllSlide();
      slides[index].style.display = 'flex';
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes, it does! Thank you very much.